# Using static fragment in Fragment Page Adapter

Tags: java, android, user-interface, static, fragment

I'm trying to develop tabs based application, and I'm using FragmentPageAdapter to do that. My class which extends FragmentPageAdapter is static class according to the Android documentation. My problem is that in  `getItem()` method I can only create new Fragment, what means that old fragment will be destroyed.
I want to keep my fragment through all the app lifecycle, so I deciced to declare local static members which will kepp my fragment all the time.
Here is code:

```
static Fragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
static Fragment listFragment = new VehiclesListFragment();
...
  @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if(position == 0 && listFragment != null) {
                return listFragment;
            } else if(position == 0) {
                listFragment = new VehiclesListFragment();
                return listFragment;
            } else if(position == 1 && mapFragment != null) {
                return mapFragment;
            } else if(position == 1) {
                mapFragment = new MapFragment();
                return mapFragment;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

I clear this static members in each Fragment like that:

```
@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    MainActivity.mapFragment = null;
}
```

My question is: Is declaring Fragment as static safe? Is it not oppose to android desing philosophy? Are there any better solution to keep Fragment in memory without creating new one, every time user switches tabs? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** 
I found answer here:  http://alexfu.github.io/blog/2013/04/22/retaining-fragments-in-fragmentpageradapter/

Comment: I thought that FragmentPageAdapter will maintain all the fragments already.

Comment: @CChi As far as I understand Android documentation it's create a new one every time.

Comment: I believe getItem don't get call every time you switch page.